# SSIS: Capture Truncation Warning from Flat File Source with "Ignore Failure" Enabled

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a 2005 SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package that is loading delimited flat files into some tables. A very small percentage of records have a text field that is *longer* than the file format specification says it can be.  Rather than try to play an ongoing game of "guess the real maximum length", the customer has requested I just truncate anything over the size in the spec.

I have set the Trunctation event to "Ignore Failure" in the Flat File Source Editor, and that takes care of my extra data.  However, it seems to be a completely silent truncation (it does not write any warning to the log).  I am concerned that if there is ever a question about what data has been truncated, I have no way to identify it.

**What is a simple way to log the fact the truncation happened?**

It would be enough to identify that the file had a truncated row in it, but if I could also specify the actual row that would be great.  Whether it is captured as part of the built in package logging or I have to make a special call makes no difference to me.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do the actual insert have a conditional split task that takes the records longer than the actual field length and puts them into a logging table. Then you can truncate the data and rejoin them to the orginal path using a Merge or Merge Join transformation.

Comment: See my reply to bobs posting of your same solution.

Comment: @JoeG, Yoou define the width of the file you are importing to have a larger size. In the file connection managre go to the advanced tab. Select the first column, hold down the shift key and selct the last column. That will select all the columns. then change the Output width column to a very high value. The default is generally 50 which I find is never large enough for the input file.

Comment: Taken to the extreme, your solution is to take an input column with "infinite" width and setting the output column to "infinite + 1" so that it won't truncate. At some point I have to set a real limit, so there will always be the potential the actual data is larger, forcing a truncate.  What I'm looking for is a way to process my data using the SSIS components, while also logging when truncation happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the truncation yourself as part of the data flow.  Set the flat file column width to a value that is very big (larger than any expected values).  You can use a conditional split to identify rows that violate the length.

In the data flow path for invalid rows, you can record the information to your log.  Then, you can convert the values to the valid length and merge them back with the valid rows. And, finally add the rows to the destination.

Comment: My problem is I can't define a width that is "larger than any expected values" because the files I'm receiving are already violating the official "maximum". So even with your solution I would still have to handle the potential of truncation, which gets me back to wondering how to log it.